# Utilize `fswatch` to improve `rsync`'s speed?

Tags: linux, macos, filesystems, rsync, watch

I have some huge folders containing about 40000 files (and much, much more gitignored files like `node_modules`), and I want to `rsync` to a remote machine.

Currently, I use a simple script like `run_rsync; fswatch -o $BASE_DIR | while read f; do run_rsync; done`. But whenever a file changes, the rsync is triggered and I see it scanning the 40000 files to find out diffs, which consumes quite a bit of CPU and time.

Thus, I wonder, since `fswatch` knows which exact file(s) are changed, can `rsync` be aware of that, and *only* look at those few files and decide what to do with them. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into inotify (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)

Comment: @mtak Thanks but I am not sure how this is to be integrated with rsync?

Comment: I was thinking maybe you could script something up that invokes rsync. I don't have time for a full and complete answer, hence why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: @mtak Thank you!